# Is there a forum or community for Ubuntu Application developers?

Tags: application-development, community, ubuntu-forums

Is there a forum or community for Ubuntu Application developers?

Chat rooms count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have several, take your pick:

- [Google+](https://plus.google.com/communities/111350780270925540549)
- [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/ubuntuappdev?ref=bookmarks)
- [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/UbuntuAppDev) (New)
- [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=417)
- [Discourse](http://discourse.ubuntu.com/c/app-development)
- [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/application-development)

Answer (score 1):

The [Development and Programming](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=310) section of Ubuntu Forums has a subforum named ["Ubuntu Application Development"](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=417).

You could also consider the [`ubuntu-app-devel` mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-app-devel/) and the `#ubuntu-app-devel` IRC channel on Freenode (can't post IRC links, so: `irc://irc.freenode.net/ubuntu-app-devel`).

Lastly, if it is development, you can always ask here, or on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).